# Can't prevent screenshot in android apk (release)

Tags: android, react-native

I'm able to prevent screenshot by setting the FLAG_SECURE.

However, FLAG_SECURE doesn't prevent screenshot after building it to APK and run it.

```
public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

    /**
     * Returns the name of the main component registered from JavaScript.
     * This is used to schedule rendering of the component.
     */
    @Override
    protected String getMainComponentName() {
        return "MyAppName";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);

    }
}
```

Any idea why? I'm running it on the same device Samsung Android 7.

***Update:***

It happens intermittently. Sometimes it blocks sometimes it allows screenshot.

Comment: I would make sure that any module/third-party add-on is using your `MainActivity` rather than something derived from `ReactActivity` as `ReactActivity` wouldn't have the FLAG_SECURE setting.